# nginx does not set x-forwarded-for header

Tags: nginx, node.js

I want to get the IP adress of the client that visits my page. My app is running behind a proxy so i set this configuration to my nginx file:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
```

Now i try to get the IP adress like this in express

```
req.ip
req.headers["x-forwarded-for"]
req.ips
req.connection.remoteAdress
```

Nothing seems to work. I also set trust proxy to true

```
app.set("trust proxy", true);
```

But the other configuration like `proxy_set_header Host` or `proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade"` are working. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What version of nginx do you use? Check furthest down on this site: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/forwarded/

Comment: @Orphans versoin nginx/1.10.3, i will your suggestions real quick

Answer (score 0):

add this config to your nginx config =>

```
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

and in express you can get ip with this

```
  let ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] ||
            req.connection.remoteAddress ||
            req.socket.remoteAddress ||
            (req.connection.socket ? req.connection.socket.remoteAddress : null);
```